# Building proj/pyproj projection string for local coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj

I'm struggling to come up with a proj string for a local county coordinate system using pyproj.  The system is defined as follows:

- Linear unit: International foot (ift)
- Geodetic datum: North American Datum of 1983 (1991)
- Vertical datum: National Geodetic Vertical Datum of 1929 (NGVD29)
- System: Central Oregon Coordinate System
- Projection: Transverse Mercator
- Latitude of grid origin: 43° 00' 00" N
- Longitude of central meridian: 121° 17' 00"W
- Northing at grid origin: 0.000 ift
- Easting at central meridian: 3,300,000.000 ift
- Scale factor on central meridian: 1.00016 (exact)

My current string is not converting correctly

```
p = Proj(r'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=43.00 +lon_0=-121.2833333 +x_0=3,300,000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +k_0=1.00016 +to_meter=0.3048 +no_defs', preserve_units=True)
```

Comment: IIRC, x_0 and x_0 are always given in meters.